# System.FormatException in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

The following code updates properties on-the-fly via mvvmcross messaging protocol.

The problem that I am facing now, when user clears either `age` or `category` textviews, then I am getting systemformat exception, I guess when `textview` gets blank, it does not parse it to a number?

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

**MainViewModel**

```
private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;
private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

public MainViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger) {

    _messenger = messenger;
    _token = messenger.Subscribe<SelectedItemMessage>(OnMessageReceived);;
}

private void OnMessageReceived(SelectedItemMessage obj)
{
    Age = obj.Age;
    Category= obj.Category;
}
```

**DetailViewModel**

```
private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;

public DetailViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger) {
    _messenger = messenger;
}

public void UpdateMethod() {
    var message = new SelectedItemMessage(this,  age, category); 
    _messenger.Publish(message, typeof(SelectedItemMessage));
}
```

**SelectedItemMessage**

```
public SelectedItemMessage(object sender, double age, int category) : base(sender)
    {
        Age = age;
        Category = category;
    }

    public double Age { get; set; }
    public int Category{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When you create your SelectedItemMessage you pass in this and then the SelectedItem. I don't see that as being part of your SelectedItemMessage constructor. Shouldn't it be passing age and category?

Comment: you are right, I have corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a value converter which converts empty string to null and you need to make `Age` property nullable. After that you will need to specify the converted in the binding:

```
public class NullableValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

and inside your view:

```
local:MvxBind="Text Age,Converter=Nullable;"
```

You can read more about value converters at [Value Converters Wiki](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters)

Comment: how do you use `age` with this converter?

Comment: By doing that I do not need to use `nullable double` any more, I mean `double?`

Comment: @hotspring: You need because the value converter returns null when the input is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot Giorgi.